# testing an api with a file and body as input

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I created a restful api to upload a file, the problem is that I need another object in order to upload the file, so I created a simple controller :

```
String uploadFile(@RequestBody DocumentInfo info,@RequestParam("file") MultiPartFile file){
   ...
}
```

My question is how I can test this API using mockito?

Comment: Could you show some more code? Is it a Spring Controller method? What's the expected usage of Mockito here?

Comment: I should test this api in order to increase the coverage (sonar), about the body of the code is simple, I called a service that handle the upload, and generaly there is no issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```java
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void parseMultipartFile_Should_Return_Ok() throws Exception {

        final MockPart file = new MockPart("file", new ClassPathResource("test.file").getInputStream().readAllBytes());
        file.getHeaders().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");

        final MockPart jsonData = new MockPart("info", "{\"some\": \"data\"}".getBytes());
        jsonData.getHeaders().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/upload")
                .part(jsonData, file))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```